# Typescript not inferring extended types correctly

Tags: typescript, next.js, types

I'm trying to make the `body` of a `NextApiRequest` more typescript friendly. I have the following code.

```js
// this is an upstream type from a library I've included here
export interface NextApiRequest {
    query: Partial<{
        [key: string]: string | string[];
    }>;
    cookies: Partial<{
        [key: string]: string;
    }>;
    body: any;
}


export type BaseSageRequest = { query?: any, method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'DELETE' | 'PATCH' | 'PUT', body?: any };
export type SageApiRequest<T extends BaseSageRequest> = NextApiRequest & {
    query: T["query"] | NextApiRequest["query"];
    method: T["method"] | NextApiRequest["method"];
    body:   T['body'] | NextApiRequest["body"];
}

export default async function createChat(
  req: SageApiRequest<{body: {lol: string}, method: 'POST'}>
) {
  // req.body is of type any, not of type {lol: string}
}
```

However, when I try to access `req.body` from within the `createChat` function, I see that `req.body` is of type `any` and not of type `{lol: string}` as I expect.

I'm certainly declaring my `BaseSageRequest` type incorrectly but I'm not sure how to fix it such that `body` takes the of `T` and not `BaseSageRequest`.

How can I set up typescript types similar to above such that `req.body` takes the type of what is passed to `SageApiRequest`? I want to enforce that any types passed to `SageApiRequest` must contain `method` and may contain `body` and `query`.

Comment: For some type `T`, the union type `any | T` is precisely equivalent to `any`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] others can paste into their own IDEs to start working on your issue without being distracted by unrelated problems.  Any types or values that are private or third-party should be defined for us, or even better, removed and replaced with built-in things.

Comment: Will do! One second.

Comment: Ok, refactored the question to not have extraneous types and to have a single example.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that totally makes sense. Do you have suggestion for how I can improve my types?

Comment: You're importing from "next"?  Could you tag the question as such so that people who know/care about that library will look at it? Conversely, unless the question depends on next you should not import the types in your example and instead replace them with some minimal locally defined thing that demonstrates the same issue.

Comment: I added the next tag

Comment: As @jcalz says, the correct approach depends on the types imported from `"next"`. However I was suggesting that you need to make `BaseSageRequest` generic as in `BaseSageRequest<TQuery, TBody> =  { query?: TQuery, method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'DELETE' | 'PATCH' | 'PUT', body?: TBody }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of struggling with the type system, I found something that works:

```
export interface BaseSageRequest extends NextApiRequest {
  method: "GET" | "POST" | "DELETE" | "PATCH" | "PUT";
}

export interface SageApiRequest<TBody = any, TQuery extends Partial<NextApiRequest['query']> = Partial<NextApiRequest['query']>> extends BaseSageRequest {
  query: TQuery;
  body: TBody;
}
```